# How to compile the current VLC version (2.2.4) on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, compiling, vlc

I tried to compile the current version of the [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Trying to achieve this I attempted the following:

- I extracted the `.xz` with `tar xvfJ vlc-2.2.4.tar.xz`
- Changed to the `vlc-2.2.4` directory
- Executed `./bootstrap`
- Executed `./configure`
- Executed `./make`

This *did not work*!
I had to install several `*-dev` packages (dependencies) via `sudo apt-get -y install *` to proceed further.

Unfortunately even this has not been sufficient to create an executable. I got stuck at this error message in the `make` process:

> video_chroma/swscale.c:39:32: fatal error: libswscale/version.h: File or directory not found

Trying to research this error was not successful.
So my full question is:

**What exact steps do I have to take to successfully compile VLC-2.2.4 on Ubuntu 12.04?**

Comment: So why not upgrade to a recent Ubuntu version? There is a VLC snap package but I also doubt you can use it in 12.04.

Comment: @xangua: Currently I'm stuck with a live version of 12.04. And secondly, because many people attempted to do the same. I'm sure that it's possible, but the details seem to be tricky. I found many others asking this question relating to this on AskUbuntu, but no answer :-(

Comment: Hey, can you please swing by the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)? I'd like to talk to you for a bit about some of the edits you've been suggesting, if that's okay with you.

Comment: The libav libs in precise are way too old for current vlc. You could build vlc statically linked to a newer ffmpeg or libav source build but the later may also prove difficult in 12.04 due to other too old libraries.

Comment: @doug: A statically linked solution would be perfectly sufficient.

Comment: @zx485: Did you manage to build VLC for 12.04?

Comment: @zx485 I have a message for you in a chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82215/review-feedback

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and this worked for me:

```
% cd contrib
% mkdir native
% cd native
% ../bootstrap
% make
```

Everything else you may need is in here: https://wiki.videolan.org/UnixCompile/

If this doesn't work - check your dependencies.